# Is data from Huygens still being analyzed in 2018?

Tags: probe, titan, scientific-data, huygens-lander

The Huygens probe landed on Saturn's moon Titan about 13 years ago and provided unique "first-hand" data about Titan. I was unable to find how many papers have been published based on this data, but my question is:

Is data from Huygens still being analyzed, or has everything provided by the probe already been utilized to the fullest extent?

Can we expect more papers based on the Huygens mission? (please note I'm only referring to the Huygens probe, as the data from Cassini will probably keep scientists busy for many more years).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick search on Google Scholar [turns up 106 articles published in 2018 using Huygens' data](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_ylo=2018&q=Huygens%20Titan&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5). So I'd say the data is still being analyzed and used.

Comment: All thanks to Boris Smeds   https://spectrum.ieee.org/tech-history/space-age/titan-calling